# In SQL(postgresql) How to group based on a "timestamp without time zone" column?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write some queries to group things based on each month in **postgresql**.

Say we have a table "crimes" which has 2 columns "activity date"(timestamp without time zone) and "zipcode"(character varying(5)), how to query the number of crimes for each month given a zipcode?

eg:
table "crimes":

```
activity date               zipcode
2014-11-22 00:52:00           12345
2014-10-22 00:52:00           12345
2014-10-24 00:52:00           12345
2014-12-22 00:52:00           54321
```

input: given zipcode"12345"

output: return

```
month        count
2014-10        2
2014-11        1
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
select
    extract(year from activity_date) as year,
    to_char(activity_date, 'Mon') as month,
    count(*) as count
from
    crimes
group by
    1,extract(month from activity_date);
```

Comment: ERROR:  function year(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 2:     year(activitydate) as year,
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function year(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 12

Comment: Thx again it works just! But what if I want it to be ordered according to date that "2014 Dec" appears before "2014 Jun". I tried "order by 1, 2" but the result is unexpected.

Comment: It seems ordered alphabetically that "Aug" appears first.

Comment: I tried "extract(month from activitydate) as month" as well. It works thx man!

Comment: I get error : activiey_date must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 4):

**How to get the month from a timestamp (with/out timezone) in PostgreSQL?**

Use the function **EXTRACT(field FROM source)**

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2
```

Link to documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Answer (score 1):

I like to use:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', activity_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS month
```

then the result would be like:

```
month                              count
2023-10-01 00:00:00.000              1
2023-11-01 00:00:00.000              2
```

and if you want to count by `week`, you could change it to:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', activity_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS week
```

or count by `year`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('year', activity_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS year
```

but if you want to count by `date`, the above SQL won't work, please stick to:

```
SELECT DATE(conversation.created_date) AS day
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Declare @zipcode int;
set @zipcode=12345;
select format(activity_date,'yyyy-MM') month ,count(1) count from ct
where zipcode=@zipcode
group by format(ad,'yyyy-MM')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**